# How to access hashmaps inside an ArrayList originated from a database?

Tags: java, database, arraylist, iterator, hashmap

I have an ArrayList with a bunch of hashmaps. Each hashmap has the name and value of a column originated from a database. How do I access the value of these columns?

The Netbeans variable inspector shows me:

```
avaliacaoList = (java.util.ArrayList) [{id_grade_curricular=5476, posicao=...
```

And the debugger presents me with the values below:

[image: ArrayList with hashmaps]

I need to iterate in the ArrayList, accessing each hashmap and his values. I tried many ways to iterate in this ArrayList, but I could not find a way to access the field **id_grade_curricular** (see orange arrow) of each "record".
Can someone help me to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a list of hashmaps and that you absolutely do need it that way.

```
for (HashMap h : avaliacaoList){
    Object result = h.get("id_grade_curricular");
    //do something
}
```

Instead of Object use whatever you are storing.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why iterating using FOR doesn't worked, so I used an iterator and retrieve the values as objects as you demonstrate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the items in the `ArrayList` are `HashMaps`. You have to then actually access the key:value pair you want.

```
for (HashMap entry : avaliacaoList){
    int value = entry.get("id_grade_curricular")
    // Do something with value here
}
```

Note here I'm assuming the type of the map is `HashMap<string,int>` since that's what your example looks like. Adjust the types accordingly if that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). You could iterate the `List` and call `Map.get()` with something like

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> avaliacaoList;
for (HashMap<String,String> map : avaliacaoList) {
  System.out.println(map.get("id_grade_curricular"));
}
```